# RoboCopy to hidden shadow drive partition; error code reads as Invalid Parameter #26 :x\

Tags: windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe, robocopy, volume-shadow-copy

I am currently attempting to set up a mirroring of my C:\ drive.  I read online that using Robocopy was the best way to set this up.  I have put together the following string of robocopy options,

```
 robocopy c:\ x:\ /e /zb /efsraw /mot:1440 /x /v /fp /np /copyall /secfix /timfix /mir /A-:H /rh:0300-0700 /pf /compress /w:n /l /x /v /ns /256 /log+:Cshdw x:\ /tee
```

my log file continues to return with ;

```
>> ERROR : Invalid Parameter #26 : "x:\"
```

I have no idea what it is that I have done wrong. A little help would be appreciated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP figured it out

Comment: So, now I'm trying to figure out how to answer my own question and close the thread.  Funny how it's the more random things that can stymie us.  

Comment: Thanks Gantendo.

Comment: I think you can delete it, but not close it or answer it for some weird reason. So just delete it.

Comment: Below your question should be a big box for your answer. In a couple of days you will be able to "accept" that answer. We do not want questions to be edited to include answers. It might help to take the [tour] to see how things work here. We also don't appreciate "EDIT" or "SOLVED" in titles as we can already easily see edits and having an accepted answer is how you show that the question is solved.

Comment: A related note: to "mirror" a drive, without further details, usually means to set up a RAID mirror. It is something different to "create a mirror of a drive" or "an exact copy of a drive", and this would more clearly indicate something robocopy would be the right solution to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The x:\ after /log+:Cshdw is what the whole problem was.